# raspberry use mplayer meet "audio device got stuck"

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, mplayer

I want to use the [raspberry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dlzn.png) pi to play audio through the Bluetooth.I google a lot of ways but did not solve the problems I encountered.I use mplayer to play audio, encountered "audio device got stuck" error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `-ao` option?

Perhaps changing audio output driver helps you.